# Must role="tab" be the direct child of a role="tablist"?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have an accordion which is structured like:

```
<section... role="tablist">
  <div>
    <h3 role="tab">Title</h3>
    <div role="tabpanel">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Does tab have to be a direct child of the tablist to conform to wai aria best practices or is it okay to be wrapped in a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Authors MUST ensure elements with role tab are *contained* in, or owned by, an element with the role tablist.
>
> <sup>https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#tab</sup>

Your example is therefore correct.

I would suggest you read through the spec to ensure you are following best ARIA practice.

For example adding the `role` on a `div` as opposed to a `section` element, [as per the best practice example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be a direct child. It is valid as long as it is a "descendant of".

Your `<div>` have no `role` in the accessibility tree so it does not affect the accessibility experience. (If the element you use *does* have a particular accessibility role then you can overwrite it with `role="none"` or `role="presentation"`.)

Valid example:

```html
<ul role="tablist">
    <li role="none">
        <a id="tab-1" href="#panel-1" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-1" tabindex="0"> Tab 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li role="none">
        <a id="tab-2" href="#panel-1" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="panel-2" tabindex="-1"> Tab 2 </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
<div class="tab-panels">
    <section id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="tab-1">
        Panel content
    </section>
    <section id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="tab-2" hidden>
        Panel content
    </section>
    ...
</div>
```